# Unable to resolve module `./createNativeWrapper`

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-gesture-handler

I am using react-native 0.58.6, and react-native-gesture-handler 1.0.16.

On IOS platform getting this error due to gesture-handler.

> > error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `./createNativeWrapper` from `/Users/Documents/Work/ReactDemoApp/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/GestureHandler.js`

Any suggestion ?

Comment: have you linked it?

Comment: Yes, Linked it. but its not working

Answer (score 0):

npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler

Linking

react-native link react-native-gesture-handler

... cd/ios 
... pod install

if you already link and install module then try this

deleting node_modules, package-lock.json and reinstall them.

rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-map-*

rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-cache*

npm start --reset-cache

Comment: Done all this stuff, but still facing this issue.